# Breaking text message marketing "promise"

Tags: united-states

A business offers a signup on their website for a text club that will send recipients deals for the business. The signup promises "We'll only text you when there's a deal." But the texts from the business are never deals.

The business seems to be lying, but is this actually a legal problem for the business? Is the answer different if some of the texts are deals but some are not? Does the quantity of messages matter?

Comment: The answer to this question might depend on how a court interprets the phrase "deal" and whether or not the messages sent by the service would be classified as such.

Comment: That's a great point. An answer that includes outcomes for various interpretations would be interesting to me!